# Do we really need "Top network askers"?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange.com, hot-questions

I was browsing the main Stack Exchange [page](https://stackexchange.com/) and came across the "Hot posts" tab. It is a fun thing to see the diversity of the entire network. Then I noticed that there is a list with "Top network askers" right beside it, which is simply a list of the authors of the questions that are listed on the left half of the page.

I suspect that there was some sort of use for this feature, or it was adapted from something similar, but in its current state I don't see any use for it.

Should we:

- adapt it to include a more relevant ranking?
- consider changing the name of the list to reflect what is actually listed?
- consider omitting it at all?

[image]

Comment: I would expect it to be the top network askers overall?

Comment: How do I access the Top Network Spammers feature? I want to engage in a little public shaming.

Comment: @rene, I have the same association when reading that text, but that is not what is depicted.

Comment: The [first column from here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues) (for the week) sorted by 'top user' would be slightly more useful/interesting.